# Вывод массива по ключу

Tags: массивы, php

С новым годом всех ХешКодовцев! Есть массив таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Myname
            [type] => 1

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Myname
            [type] => 1

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Myname
            [type] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Myname
            [type] => 3

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Myname
            [type] => 1
        )
...
)
```

Мне нужно вывести где type == 1, пробовал так че то не канает ((

```
`array_keys($array_name, "type" == "1")`
```

F1 плиз!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходный массив:

```
$a = array(
  array('type' => 1, 'name' => 'test0'),
  array('type' => 2, 'name' => 'test1'),
  array('type' => 1, 'name' => 'test2'),
  array('type' => 1, 'name' => 'test3')
);
```

Фильтр:

```
var_export(array_filter($a, function($v) {
  return $v['type'] == 1;
}));
```

Результат:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'type' => 1,
    'name' => 'test0',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'type' => 1,
    'name' => 'test2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'type' => 1,
    'name' => 'test3',
  ),
)
```

Пожалуйста.